# undefined reference to vTable for MainFrame in eclipse using Qt

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I am currently working on a project where we need to integrate Qt into eclipse. I have it mostly figured out. I am able to get intellisense to work with the Qt files. I am even able to successfully compile a Qt project!

I setup my external tools to run Qmake (for convenience because running it from the command line is annoying).

Like I said, I have it mostly working. When I go to create an executable from the project, the linker is called and I get an error: "undefined reference to `vtable for MainFrame'"

Ok, so looking into it some more, and going to stackoverflow, a number of answers basically point to the issue being the MOC. When I add a new class that uses the Q_OBJECT macro, I need to re run QMake.... Ok, So I re run Qmake, generate the build files, an I make sure that my build configuration is using an external makefile for the project.

Everything seems like it should be working.... but it is not. I am still getting the error...

So, has anyone done any work with Qt integration in eclipse? I am a little stumped on this issue and I am looking to get this solved as soon as possible.

MainFrame.h

```
class MainFrame : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainFrame(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainFrame();

private:

    //! The menu bar for the main window
    /*!
        The menu bar is kind of like a container where it contains all of the listings of the different
        wxMenu classes.
        For additional documentation on the wxMenuBar class, refer to the following link:
        https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html
    */
    QMenuBar *p_menubar = new QMenuBar();

    QMenu *p_menuFile = new QMenu();

    QMenu *p_menuEdit = new QMenu();

    QMenu *p_menuView = new QMenu();

    //! The problem menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_menuProblem = new QMenu;

    //! The grid menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_menuGrid = new QMenu;

    //! The properties menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_menuProperties = new QMenu;

    //! The mesh menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_menuMesh = new QMenu;

    //! The analysis menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_analysisMenu = new QMenu;

    //! The help menu for the menu bar
    /*!
        For additional documentation on the wxMenu class, refer to the following link:
        http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html
    */
    QMenu *p_menuHelp = new QMenu;


    /** Menu Actions **/


    QAction *p_newAction;
    QAction *p_SaveAction;
    QAction *p_SaveAsAction;
    QAction *p_OpenAction;
    QAction *p_ExitAction;


    void setupMenuActions();

public slots:

    void newActionSlot(bool checked);

    void saveActionSlot(bool checked);

    void saveAsActionSlot(bool checked);

    void openActionSlot(bool checked);

    void exitActionSlot(bool checked);

};
```

MainFrame.cpp

```
#include <MainFrame.h>

MainFrame::MainFrame(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupMenuActions();

    p_menuFile = this->menuBar()->addMenu("File");
    p_menuFile->addAction(p_newAction);
    p_menuFile->addAction(p_SaveAction);
    p_menuFile->addAction(p_SaveAsAction);
    p_menuFile->addAction(p_OpenAction);
    p_menuFile->addSeparator();
    p_menuFile->addAction(p_ExitAction);

    p_menuEdit = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Edit");

    p_menuView = this->menuBar()->addMenu("View");

    p_menuProblem = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Problem");

    p_menuGrid = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Grid");

    p_menuProperties = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Properties");

    p_menuMesh = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Mesh");

    p_analysisMenu = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Analysis");

    p_menuHelp = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Help");
}




void MainFrame::setupMenuActions()
{
    p_newAction = new QAction("&New", this);
    p_newAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::New);
    connect(p_newAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(newActionSlot(bool)));

    p_SaveAction = new QAction("&Save", this);
    p_SaveAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Save);
    connect(p_SaveAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(saveActionSlot(bool)));

    p_SaveAsAction = new QAction("&Save As", this);
    p_SaveAsAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::SaveAs);
    connect(p_SaveAsAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(saveAsActionSlot(bool)));

    p_OpenAction = new QAction("&Open", this);
    p_OpenAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Open);
    connect(p_OpenAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(openActionSlot(bool)));

    p_ExitAction = new QAction("&Open", this);
    connect(p_ExitAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(exitActionSlot(bool)));

}


MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{

}
```

FileMenu.cpp

```
#include <MainFrame.h>


void MainFrame::newActionSlot(bool checked)
{
    /*
    if(_UIState == systemState::MODEL_DEFINING || _UIState == systemState::PHYSICS_CHOOSING || _UIState == systemState::SIMULATING || _UIState == systemState::VIEWING_RESULTS)
    {
        // Create a message box confirming that the user would like to create a new file
        if(wxMessageBox("Create New File?", "New File", wxOK | wxCANCEL | wxICON_QUESTION) == wxCANCEL)
            return;
    }
    enableToolMenuBar(false);
    _problemDefinition.defintionClear();
    _saveFilePath = "";
    if(_UIState == systemState::MODEL_DEFINING)
    {
        delete(_model);
    }
    createProblemChoosingClient();
    */
}

void MainFrame::saveActionSlot(bool checked)
{
    /*
    if(_saveFilePath != "")
    {
        save(_saveFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        wxFileDialog saveFileDialog(this, "Save File", "", "", "", wxFD_SAVE | wxFD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT | wxFD_CHANGE_DIR);
        if(saveFileDialog.ShowModal() != wxID_CANCEL)
        {
            wxString appendedTitle = "Omni-FEM - ";
            wxString fileName;
            if(saveFileDialog.GetFilename().Contains(wxString(".omniFEM")))
            {
                std::string tempFileName = saveFileDialog.GetFilename().ToStdString();
                for(int i = 0; i < (tempFileName.length() - 8); i++)
                    fileName += wxString(tempFileName[i]);
            }
            else
                fileName = saveFileDialog.GetFilename();
            _problemDefinition.setName(fileName);
            appendedTitle.append(_problemDefinition.getName());
            this->SetTitle(appendedTitle);
            _saveFilePath = saveFileDialog.GetPath();
            _problemDefinition.setSaveFilePath(saveFileDialog.GetDirectory());
            save(_saveFilePath);
        }
    }
    */
}

void MainFrame::saveAsActionSlot(bool checked)
{
    /*
    wxFileDialog saveFileDialog(this, "Save File As", "", "", "", wxFD_SAVE | wxFD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT | wxFD_CHANGE_DIR);

    if(saveFileDialog.ShowModal() != wxID_CANCEL)
    {
        wxString appendedTitle = "Omni-FEM - ";
        wxString fileName;
        if(saveFileDialog.GetFilename().Contains(wxString(".omniFEM")))
        {
            std::string tempFileName = saveFileDialog.GetFilename().ToStdString();
            for(int i = 0; i < (tempFileName.length() - 8); i++)
                fileName += wxString(tempFileName[i]);
        }
        else
            fileName = saveFileDialog.GetFilename();

        _problemDefinition.setName(fileName);
        appendedTitle.append(_problemDefinition.getName());
        this->SetTitle(appendedTitle);
        _saveFilePath = saveFileDialog.GetPath();
        _problemDefinition.setSaveFilePath(saveFileDialog.GetDirectory());
        save(_saveFilePath);
    }
    */
}

void MainFrame::openActionSlot(bool checked)
{
    /*
    wxFileDialog openFileDialog(this, "Open File", "", "", "*omniFEM", wxFD_OPEN | wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wxFD_CHANGE_DIR);

    if(openFileDialog.ShowModal() != wxID_CANCEL)
    {
        if(_UIState != systemState::MODEL_DEFINING)
        {
            createModelDefiningClient();
        }

        if(_model)
        {
            _model->deleteMesh();
            _model->SetSize(this->GetClientSize() - wxSize(12, 12));
        }

        wxString appendedTitle = "Omni-FEM - ";
        wxString fileName;
        _problemDefinition.setSaveFilePath(openFileDialog.GetDirectory());

        std::string tempFileName = openFileDialog.GetFilename().ToStdString();
        for(int i = 0; i < (tempFileName.length() - 8); i++)
            fileName += wxString(tempFileName[i]);
        appendedTitle.append(fileName.ToStdString());
        this->SetTitle(appendedTitle);
        _saveFilePath = openFileDialog.GetPath();
        _problemDefinition.defintionClear();
        load(openFileDialog.GetPath().ToStdString());

        _model->Refresh(true);
//      _model->Update();
//      _model->UpdateWindowUI();
    }
    */
}



void MainFrame::exitActionSlot(bool checked)
{

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainFrame.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainFrame mainProgram;
    mainProgram.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Note:

I am not going to use QtCreator for this project.

For project reasons beyond my control, eclipse is the toolchain we are using. So do not say that I need to switch to QtCreator. Will it be easier? Probably. But the toolchain we are using is Eclipse.

Anyways, I got it partially working. I just need to solve the vtable linking error and I think that I will be able to fully build a Qt project in eclipse

**Update:**

ok, I was able to create a very simplistic program seperate from my main program to include only the above files. I am still getting the error described above. Here is a copy of the .pro file that is generated after running qmake:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Tue May 12 19:25:49 2020
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = QTTest3
INCLUDEPATH += .

# The following define makes your compiler warn you if you use any
# feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Input
HEADERS += MainFrame.h
SOURCES += main.cpp MainFrame.cpp MenuFile.cpp
```

Copy of a clean build:

```
19:30:57 **** Build of configuration Debug for project QTTest3 ****
make all 
Building file: ../MainFrame.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtHelp -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3DInput -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"MainFrame.d" -MT"MainFrame.o" -o "MainFrame.o" "../MainFrame.cpp"
Finished building: ../MainFrame.cpp

Building file: ../MenuFile.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I/home/phillip/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtHelp -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3DInput -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"MenuFile.d" -MT"MenuFile.o" -o "MenuFile.o" "../MenuFile.cpp"
Finished building: ../MenuFile.cpp

Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/home/phillip/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtHelp -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/ -I/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3DInput -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: QTTest3
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/name/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -L/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -o "QTTest3"  ./MainFrame.o ./MenuFile.o ./main.o   -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui
./MainFrame.o: In function `MainFrame::MainFrame(QWidget*)':
/home/name/eclipse-workspace/QTTest3/Debug/../MainFrame.cpp:10: undefined reference to `vtable for MainFrame'
makefile:44: recipe for target 'QTTest3' failed
/home/name/eclipse-workspace/QTTest3/Debug/../MainFrame.cpp:10: undefined reference to `vtable for MainFrame'
./MainFrame.o: In function `MainFrame::~MainFrame()':
/home/name/eclipse-workspace/QTTest3/Debug/../MainFrame.cpp:65: undefined reference to `vtable for MainFrame'
/home/name/eclipse-workspace/QTTest3/Debug/../MainFrame.cpp:65: undefined reference to `vtable for MainFrame'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [QTTest3] Error 1

19:31:01 Build Failed. 6 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.294ms)
```

**Settings:**

C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols
For the settings, my "include directories" "includes path" is as follows:

```
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtGui
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtHelp
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3DInput
```

Note this was copied from my main project

Symbols is none.

Libraries is Qt5Core, Qt5Widgets, Qt5Gui

Library Paths is:

```
/home/name/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib
/home/name/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib
```

Everything is default.

C/C++ Build:
For this, I do have the checkbox checked for Makefiles automatically. Everything is defaults

Settings:
Under tool Settings, I made a change. In the miscellaneos section, I added a flag -fPIC. The compiler told me to do this becuase I can't compile without it.

Everything else is defaults.

Comment: Did the build process generate a `moc_MainFrame.cpp` (or similarly named file) that defines the necessary QObject boilerplate? Is the compiled moc file linked into the final executable? Show your QMake `.pro` file and the output of a clean build.

Comment: could you show the settings you set in eclipse to compile with qmake in addition to the .pro

Comment: Hey guys, I updated the question to include the items. There is no moc created. I inlucded the .pro that is created by running qmake. I also have qmake generating a makefile. My idea is for eclipse to use the makefile. Anyways, later today I will be creating a blank project and placing the Qt code in that to help refine the settings. Right now, this is directly in the project that I am working on so the .pro file is huge since it contains all of the files (src and include). More to come later.

Comment: Updated with new information. I created a simplistic test application and still got the same results. I have added the info that you are requesting as it relates to the test application above